# I need help extracting football standings from website using php

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping, html-table

I need to fetch the HTML table using PHP. How can I do it?

References:

Table to be parsed: http://epsachaias.gr/?page_id=221&cat=4&group=151

I tried this:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Standings</h1>
        <?php 
            $html = file_get_contents('http://epsachaias.gr/?page_id=221&cat=4&group=206');

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
            libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

            $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
            $trs = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

            $output = [];
            for ($itr = 0; $itr < $trs->length; $itr++) 
            {
                $tds = $trs->item($itr)->getElementsByTagName('td');
                if ($tds->length == 22) 
                {
                    $output[] = new team($tds);
                }
            }

            var_dump($output);
        ?>
```

But I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'team' not found.

Then I tried to add this code:

```
    class stats
{
    private $n;
    private $i;
    private $or;
    private $cplus;
    private $cminus;

    public function __construct($n, $i, $or, $cplus, $cminus)
    {
        $this->n = $n;
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->or = $or;
        $this->cplus = $cplus;
        $this->cminus = $cminus;
    }

    function getN()
    {
        return $this->n;
    }

    function getI()
    {
        return $this->i;
    }

    function getOr()
    {
        return $this->or;
    }

    function getCplus()
    {
        return $this->cplus;
    }

    function getCminus()
    {
        return $this->cminus;
    }
}

class team
{
    private $position;
    private $name;
    private $score;
    private $ag;
    private $dk;
    private $together;
    private $within;
    private $out;
    private $penalties;

    public function __construct(DOMNodeList $nodes)
    {
        if ($nodes->length == 22) {
            $this->position = (int) $nodes->item(0)->textContent;
            $this->name = $nodes->item(2)->textContent;
            $this->score = (int) $nodes->item(3)->textContent;
            $this->ag = (int) $nodes->item(4)->textContent;
            $this->dk = (int) $nodes->item(5)->textContent;

            $this->together = new stats((int)$nodes->item(6)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(7)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(8)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(9)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(10)->textContent);

            $this->within = new stats(  (int)$nodes->item(11)->textContent,
                                        (int)$nodes->item(12)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(13)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(14)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(15)->textContent);

            $this->out = new stats(     (int)$nodes->item(16)->textContent,
                                        (int)$nodes->item(17)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(18)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(19)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(20)->textContent);

            $this->penalties = (int) $nodes->item(21)->textContent;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect input data");
        }
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getScore()
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    public function getAg()
    {
        return $this->ag;
    }

    public function getDk()
    {
        return $this->dk;
    }

    public function getTogether()
    {
        return $this->together;
    }

    public function getWithin()
    {
        return $this->within;
    }

    public function getOut()
    {
        return $this->out;
    }

    public function getPenalties()
    {
        return $this->penalties;
    }
}
```

But again I am getting this error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to be aware that this solution is based on the current structure of that site.**

You can use `DOMDocument` object to parse HTML that you can get by `file_get_contents` like in this code

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://epsachaias.gr/?page_id=221&cat=4&group=151');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$trs = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$output = [];
for ($itr = 0; $itr < $trs->length; $itr++) {
    $tds = $trs->item($itr)->getElementsByTagName('td');

    if ($tds->length == 22) {
        $row = [];
        for ($itd = 0; $itd < $tds->length; $itd++) {
            $row[] = $tds->item($itd)->textContent;
        }
        $output[] = $row;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

The `$output` is your final array.

If you want to provide a better access for your parsed data then you can use some class and objects. For example you can prepare one class for statistic group and another for the team like in this code

```
class stats
{
    private $n;
    private $i;
    private $or;
    private $cplus;
    private $cminus;

    public function __construct($n, $i, $or, $cplus, $cminus)
    {
        $this->n = $n;
        $this->i = $i;
        $this->or = $or;
        $this->cplus = $cplus;
        $this->cminus = $cminus;
    }

    function getN()
    {
        return $this->n;
    }

    function getI()
    {
        return $this->i;
    }

    function getOr()
    {
        return $this->or;
    }

    function getCplus()
    {
        return $this->cplus;
    }

    function getCminus()
    {
        return $this->cminus;
    }
}

class team
{
    private $position;
    private $name;
    private $score;
    private $ag;
    private $dk;
    private $together;
    private $within;
    private $out;
    private $penalties;

    public function __construct(DOMNodeList $nodes)
    {
        if ($nodes->length == 22) {
            $this->position = (int) $nodes->item(0)->textContent;
            $this->name = $nodes->item(2)->textContent;
            $this->score = (int) $nodes->item(3)->textContent;
            $this->ag = (int) $nodes->item(4)->textContent;
            $this->dk = (int) $nodes->item(5)->textContent;

            $this->together = new stats((int)$nodes->item(6)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(7)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(8)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(9)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(10)->textContent);

            $this->within = new stats(  (int)$nodes->item(11)->textContent,
                                        (int)$nodes->item(12)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(13)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(14)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(15)->textContent);

            $this->out = new stats(     (int)$nodes->item(16)->textContent,
                                        (int)$nodes->item(17)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(18)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(19)->textContent, 
                                        (int)$nodes->item(20)->textContent);

            $this->penalties = (int) $nodes->item(21)->textContent;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect input data");
        }
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getScore()
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    public function getAg()
    {
        return $this->ag;
    }

    public function getDk()
    {
        return $this->dk;
    }

    public function getTogether()
    {
        return $this->together;
    }

    public function getWithin()
    {
        return $this->within;
    }

    public function getOut()
    {
        return $this->out;
    }

    public function getPenalties()
    {
        return $this->penalties;
    }
}
```

Because I guess thay you only want to read parsed data then I provided only read operation for all of the object properties. If you want to change them then ofcourse you have add setters or make properties public (and delete unwanted methods).

To preapre a collection with parsed data you can use this code

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://epsachaias.gr/?page_id=221&cat=4&group=151');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$trs = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$output = [];
for ($itr = 0; $itr < $trs->length; $itr++) {
    $tds = $trs->item($itr)->getElementsByTagName('td');

    if ($tds->length == 22) {
        $output[] = new team($tds);
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Before in `$output` you had a simple array with values - now you have a collection of objects. If you for example want to get the `ΟΜΑΔΑ` of the second team with value in the `ΣΥΝΟΛΟ -> Ν` cell then you can simply use this code

```
echo "{$output[1]->getName()}: {$output[1]->getTogether()->getN()}";
```

and on your output you will get

> Άνω Καστρίτσι: 21

Comment: thank you for your help but with my code I had the same result.But what I want is to make a link between the cells and the variables
(`ex.  first cell ->standing
second cell->team name etc.`)

Comment: @l.g.karolos I provide a solution with class and object. I'm not sure about translations so probably you have to refactor names in classes.

Comment: Thank you for you help I edited the question because I still can't figure ou how to do that

Comment: If you can write me the code where you put everything in a table each column because I don't understand.

Comment: Try the first codeblock from my answer (just copy/paste it) - it's preparing simple array. If you want the HTML array then I will improve the code later.

Comment: Sorry man I had a type error and could not see it .That works perfectly! 
Now I am trying to make a table of these object . `for ($team=0; $team < 14 ; $team++) { 
 echo "{$output[$team]->getPosition()}|{$output[$team]->getName()}|{$output[$team]->getPoints()}|{$output[$team]->getWins()}|{$output[$team]->getDraws()}|{$output[$team]->getLoses()}|{$output[$team]->getHomewins()}|{$output[$team]->getHomedraws()}|{$output[$team]->getHomeloses()}|{$output[$team]->getAwaywins()}|{$output[$team]->getAwaydraws()}|{$output[$team]->getAwayloses()}";
}` I changed some classes and I get this as a result

Comment: `1|  name1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 2|  name2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0 3|  name3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0` How can I make a table out of this ?Thanks again

Comment: To make a HTML table you need to replace your FOR loop with something like this  `echo "<table>
   <tr>
    <td>Position</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Points</td>
    <td>Wins</td>  
    <!-- and the rest of fields -->
   </tr>";
for ($team=0; $team < 14 ; $team++) {
 echo "<tr>
  <td>{$output[$team]->getPosition()}</td>
  <td>{$output[$team]->getName()}‌​</td>
  <td>{$output[$team]->ge‌​tPoints()}</td>
  <td>{$output[‌​$team]->getWins()}</td>
  <!-- and the rest of fields -->
 </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';`

Comment: Love you :D This is exactly what I wanted .